# C - Reading from a file and saving the info on a variable

Tags: c, file, variables

im having a problem reading from these 2 files bellow, file1 and file2, and then saving their information in 2 variables. 
From the file1 i want to save the name of channels, and from the file2 i want to save the name of the users and the channel where they are signed.

I was thinking of creating 2 typedef struct(shown bellow) and then create 2 variables(shown bellow) and open the files and put the info on those lists.

I also know of another way to do it which is making a 2D array like this char[100][100], the only problem with both these solutions is that I have to impose an upper limit on the amount of the channels the list/array has.

Im not sure if these are the best ways to do it or if there is a better and easier way to do it, could you guys help?

If you guys need any more information just say so, Thanks!

Edit1: i've added the read from the file1 code that i have right now and i think it is working or so it seems but my problem/question was more of is it the right way to save the information to a variable or is there a better/easier way to do it? thanks.

```
Channel channels[MAX_CHANNELS];

Registration registrations[MAX_REGISTRATIONS];

typedef struct{
    char name_channel[20];
    int id;
} Channel;

typedef struct{
    char username[50];
    char name_channel[20];
} Registration;
```

File1:

```
General
SO
PCD
FBD
```

File2:

```
2016-09-26 14:00:01 paul General
2016-09-26 14:01:11 mary SO
2016-09-27 10:33:17 paul SO
2016-09-27 13:32:10 rachel General
2016-09-27 13:32:12 rachel FBD
```

code to read the file(i have only done the file1 yet).

```
    File *file1 = fopen("channels.txt", "r");
    if(file1==NULL){ perror("Reading error: "); exit(1); } ;

    char line[100];
    int i = 0;
    int w=0;
    for(w;w<MAX_CHANNELS;w++){
        channels[w].id=-1;
        strcpy(channels[w].name, "n");
    }
    while(fgets(line, 100, file1) != NULL){

        printf("Line read: %s", line);   
        line[ strlen(line) -1 ] = 0;
        Channel a;
        strcpy(a.name , line);
        a.id=1;
        channels[i]=a;
        i++;
    }

    fclose(canais);
    int k;
    for(k=0; k<MAX_CHANNELS; k++){
        if(channels[k].id!=-1)
            printf("testing var with channels: %s\n", channels[k].name);
    }
```

Comment: I might be getting senile -  it is old age - but where is the code to read a file

Comment: i've added the code to read the file1, though i havent started on the file2, my question was if there was a better way to do it

Comment: `line[ strlen(line) -1 ] = 0;` will shorten `line` even if the line does not end with a `'\n'`  (maybe the last line?).  Better to use `line[strcspn(line,"\n")] = = '\0';` which handles not only the last line problem, but rare lines that deign with an embedded null character.

Answer (score 1):

Just a few tips that might help(in the code comments) :) I think its fine the way you are doing it. I think this is extensible as well since you can add a new member to a struct if you want to enrich you data further. I have seen strtok used to parse through data quite a bit. Strtok should eliminate the need for you to overwrite the newline due to the way it works.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MYSTRINGLEN (50) // In general "magic numbers" 
//in code makes it hard to read, though these are fairly apparent, 
//but try using #define where you can

typedef struct {
  char name[MYSTRINGLEN];
//  int id;
}Channel;

typedef struct {
  char username[MYSTRINGLEN];
  char name[MYSTRINGLEN];
} Registration;


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  int i = 0;
  //int w = 0; not needed
  int k = 0;
  char line[100];

  Channel channels[BUFSIZ] = {{{0}}}; // num of brackets depends on num of nested data structure
  Registration registrations[BUFSIZ] = {{{0}}};

/* init all to zero instead w/ bracket syntax
  for (w = 0; w < BUFSIZ; w++){ 
    channels[w].id = -1;
    strcpy(channels[w].name, "n");
  }
*/
  FILE * file1 = fopen("channels.txt", "r");
//Many people use strtok to get done what you are doing here if you are interested
  while(fgets(line,100,file1)){  // do not need to explicitly state NULL
    printf("Line read %s\n", line);
    line[strlen(line) -1] = 0;
    //Channel a; You have already initialized a whole array of struct, just use them
    strcpy(channels[i].name, line);
    //a.id = 1;
    //channels[i]=a;
    i++; 
  }

  fclose(file1);

  for(k = 0; k < BUFSIZ; k++){
    if (0 != channels[k].name[0]){ //can test if string was populated, dont need id flag
      printf("testing var with channels: %s\n", channels[k].name);
    }
  }  

  return 0;
}
de here
```